# Sort/lookup data by multiple criteria AND from latest date in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have thousands of records that have four columns worth of data shown here (bolded records addressed below):

---

AccountNo.....Type of Product....AmountPaid....SubscribeDate
**1001................Wood....................912.34...........03/01/2016**

1002................Wood....................987.21...........06/01/2015
1003................Diamonds.............500.24...........04/01/2015
**1001................Coal......................125.32...........04/01/2014**

1003................Wood....................789.25...........09/01/2015
1543................Coal......................147.25...........07/01/2015
**1001................Wood....................958.25...........03/01/2016**

1003................Steel.....................658.51...........03/01/2016
1008................Wood....................587.95...........02/01/2015
**1001................Steel.....................458.58...........06/01/2015**

1232................Wood....................951.21...........06/01/2015

---

What I am trying to do is find out what is the total amount paid for *all* types of products belonging to an 'AccountNo' for the *latest* 'SubscribeDate'

So for example I can confirm Account no. '1001'paid 1870.59 per their *latest* subscribe date of 03/01/2016.

I would like to know this for every account number.  I've tried index/match for the multiple criteria, but I couldn't figure out how to pull *only* for the latest date in the subscribe date field.  Then I made a pivot table and sorted per max date, but couldn't figure out how to pull the rest of the data in due to the different types of products and amounts paid.

Can anyone help me?  I figure that this is a very simple thing, but I am totally stumped.

Comment: Ran into a question very similar to this just the other day, would VBA be acceptable is someone wanted to give you an answer going down that route?  Are helper cell or additional columns acceptable?

Comment: VBA would be fine! I just need a solution :( Lol.  Thanks for replying. I will check it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I pulled this code from another [here](http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/EIK284/LX317911811.htm).  Its was not working with dates so I had to tweak it a little.  Similar to Excel's built in SUMIF, this User Defined Function pulls the MAXIMUM out of a range where a criteria has to be met.

```
Public Function MAXIF(ByVal rgeCriteria As Range, _
                      ByVal sCriteria As String, _
                      ByVal rgeMaxRange As Range) As Single
                      
Dim iconditioncolno As Integer
Dim inumberscolno As Integer
Dim lrowno As Long
Dim sngmax As Variant
Dim vcellvalue As Variant

        
   iconditioncolno = rgeCriteria.Column
   inumberscolno = rgeMaxRange.Column
   For lrowno = 1 To rgeCriteria.Rows.Count
      vcellvalue = rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, inumberscolno).Value
      If rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, iconditioncolno).Value = sCriteria And (IsNumeric(vcellvalue) = True Or IsDate(vcellvalue) = True) Then

      'I had to add the IsDate and OR to the above check to make it work with dates

         If sngmax = 0 Then sngmax = vcellvalue
         If vcellvalue > sngmax Then sngmax = vcellvalue
      End If
      
      If sngmax <> 0 And IsEmpty(vcellvalue) = True Then Exit For
   Next lrowno
    
   For lrowno = 1 To rgeCriteria.Rows.Count
      vcellvalue = rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, inumberscolno).Value
      If rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, iconditioncolno).Value = sCriteria And _
         IsNumeric(vcellvalue) = True Then
         If rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, inumberscolno).Value > sngmax Then
            sngmax = rgeCriteria.Parent.Cells(rgeCriteria.Row + lrowno - 1, inumberscolno).Value
         End If
      End If
      
      If sngmax <> 0 And IsEmpty(vcellvalue) = True Then Exit For
   Next lrowno
    
   MAXIF = sngmax
End Function
```

I placed the code in the module section.  I then combined the new UDF with the built in SUMIFS to generate this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C12,A2:A12,F2,D2:D12,MAXIF(A2:A12,F2,D2:D12))
```

now since you have a thousand rows of data or so, you might not be looking forward to defining all those range. If you are ok with looking at an entire column (all 1048576 rows) then you can do the following:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,F2,D:D,MAXIF(A:A,F2,D:D))
```

OR you could do it with OFFSET and COUNT but it gets ugly and hard to read fast.

[image: Example results]

### UPDATE

As an alternative in case you were also interested in knowing what the latest date was is adjacent to the account number your are inquiring about you could put the MAXIF() formula on its own:

MAXIF(A2:A12,F2,D2:D12)

Then in the column beside it you could do a sumproduct instead of a sumifs.

```
=sumproduct(($A$2:$A$12=F2)*($D$2:$D$12=G2)*($C$2:$C$12))
```

Not sure if its any better than using sumifs, but it is another option for you.  One of the nice things about this approach would be if you have a specific date you wanted to search for you would simply type it in and replace the MAXIF formula with the specific date.

Comment: Yes the .... were spacings.  These are in conventional excel cell's.  The date field is also numbers.

Comment: @MiguelM  previous answer was not working for you as it only works with unique dates for each client account.  So I wiped out that code and brought in this code from another site, gave it a minor tweak, and voila a solution that hopefully works for you.  I provided you with a screen shot to show that it is totalling to your example data.

Comment: ForwardEd. This works perfectly. One drawback though. I don't want to look this up on a one by one basis. I want to perform this for every "AccountNo" in the first column. In which in my original file, I have probably 75k records. Is there a way I can use this (brilliant) script to quickly run for all AccountNo's to pull all of their "AmountPaid's" per their latest "Subscribedate"? So what I did was pull in the unique "AccountNo's" into column F, and then dragged the formula down. However with 75k, this would take approximately 29 hours after timing 10 rows processing. Any faster way?

Comment: That would be a slightly different question.  You want to generate a new list of unique numbers or more commonly refered to as "remove duplicates from a column".  Take a look for that question as it has been asked many a time.  If you can find you answer, just copy this formula down beside your list.

Comment: Yes, I've filtered out the duplciates, and placed the unique Accountno's in column F.  But, when I drag down the second column,  it takes a while to render the information (which is ok) just want to know if there is a faster way.

Comment: if you did (A:A) instead of A1::A1000 that would be one reason why it is potentially slower.  part of the reason its slow is if you have 75K unique accounts. and you have 100K records, then you are looking at 7.5M X number of column of cells that are being looked at.  When you are doing it just once, it only 100KXnumber of columns.  Big difference in the amount of data.

Comment: You could also take this chunk of code to "Code Review" and ask if there is a way to speed it up there. or post a new question pointing to this one and ask if there is a way to make it go faster since strictly speaking this is not JUST code but code and built in formulas.

Comment: PS:  The brilliant script (VBA) code was not mine.  I just tweaked the part to make it works with dates and not just numbers.  The rest belongs to that other website I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

use the below formula to get your result.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"1001",D:D,"03/01/2016")
```

If you want all the datas in one shot. you may go for VBA

Comment: how do you know that 03/01/2016 is the most recent date over the 1k or so records?

Comment: @ForwardEd. Good Question. But we need to parse the date and account number as parameter